# Invert col in small size with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-6">hi 1</div>
        <div class = "col-md-6>hi 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, it shows: `hi 1    |    hi 2`

and in xs (small screen) i'd like it to show:

```
 hi 2
 hi 1
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Use the push and pull classes. The docs are at GetBootstrap.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source, put it in the order that you want for smaller viewports, in the min-width of your choice (sm, md, lg) use the push and pull classes.

[image]

[image]

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/nexax/1/edit

```
 <div class="container">
      
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
        hi 2
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
        hi 1
      </div>

      </div><!--/.row-->    
    
  </div><!--/.container-->
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I couldn't understand how it worked, now I get it!

Answer (score 2):

Remember the rule "**mobile first**"

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class = "col-md-6 pull-right">hi 2</div>
        <div class = "col-md-6 pull-right">hi 1</div>
      </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Bootply Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/UqvsANINR2)

Comment: It is improper to have cols as direct children of a col like this. You're missing an intervening `row`.

Comment: @cvrebert I'm not missing anything. If there's no practical need to define a new row (usually for nested columns), then there's no reason to clutter the code.

Comment: Yes, there is a practical reason, the row clears and it removes the padding on the left and right of the row with negative margins. So nesting columns in columns is not done without a surrounding row on the nest makes for more padding to deal with, but this is not necessary for the OP question the docs show us how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Real simple, below is the following code for that:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">hi 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">hi 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that put `hi 1` above `hi 2` on the xs view port?

Comment: Yes. It would. Was that not the goal?